# Issue with ko.toJSON and Computed observable

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an issue with knockout computed observable and toJSON functions. I have created a [**Fiddle Example**](http://jsbin.com/eqejov/5/edit). In this example i have a model :

```
function VM()
{
  this.Name = ko.observable("Tom");
  this.Age = ko.observable(23);
  
  //I want this computed evaluate only 
  //when name will change. So i put Name observable 
  //inside it.
  ko.computed(function(){
     this.Name();
    //send only after dom is initiallized
     if(initialized){   
        Server.Sync(this);
     }
  }, this).extend({ throttle: 500 });
}

function Server()
{
}

Server.Sync = function(data)
{
  alert("send");
  var jsonData = ko.toJSON(data); //This is the problamatic code which.. 
  //increases the computed dependency. After executing this code the..
  //computed function is now evaluates on Age also which i do not want.
  
  //send jsonData
};
```

In this model i want my computed evaluates only when user will change the Name observable property. An its works fine until *Server.Sync* function executed. In *Sync* function i am creating the JSON object from ViewModel object through *toJSON* function and *this code first unwrap the observables and than create its Clean Js object than than through Stringify it will create the JSON*. Now i think during unwrapping the observables the Age observable dependency increases for my computed observable and now it is evaluating  whenever user change the Age property also.

If my interpretation is correct than, How can i avoid this ?

Comment: Does age have to be observable? It seems like you do not want to observe change on that data.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is "this" variable. You are accessing the main viewmodel in the computed. the reference is passed and when that changes, the computed value now re-evaluates.

your best bet is to do something like this.

Create a local variable that has the data you want to pass and pass that to sync.

Here is an updated JSBin from your fiddle. I removed this from the computed, and used a local variable to access it.

http://jsbin.com/eqejov/9/edit

```
function VM()
{
  var self = this;
  self.Name = ko.observable("Tom");
    self.Age = ko.observable(23);

var localValue = {
   Name: self.Name(),
   Age: self.Age()
};

    //I want this computed evaluate only 
    //when name will change. So i put Name observable 
    //inside it.
    ko.computed(function(){
       self.Name();
      //send only after dom is initiallized
       if(initialized){   
          Server.Sync(localVariable);
       }
    }).extend({ throttle: 500 });
  }
```

Comment: Btw, this won't give you the latest values.